# Is api schema available for docusign connect webhooks?

Tags: docusignapi

Working with Connect REST v2.1 webhooks with Aggregated option and can't find detailed list of fields.

JSON SIM is well documented https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/improved-json-sim-event-model/#eventreference
However I would like to see list for aggregated which contains different structure.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Connect FAQ](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/faq/) "The full range of triggering events is supported by the eSignature REST API v2.1 in the JSON SIM data format. The legacy eSignature REST API v2.0 and eSignature SOAP API support a limited range of triggering events in XML SIM or Aggregate format."

You will have to use v2.0 to use the Aggregate format which is described in more detail on [this page](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/legacy-message-formats/).

Comment: Second link does not contain schema nor list of available fields.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the schema for Aggregate XML Connect?  The Connect XML schema used is that of the eSignature SOAP API.  Schema is here:
https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsx.xsd